# How to count the frequency of words existing in a text using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, word-frequency

I have a python script that reads the text and applies preprocess functions in order to do the analysis.
The problem is that I want to count the frequency of words but the system crash and displays the below error.

> File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 208, in tag_and_save
>        file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+str(freq_tagged_data[word])+")\n") TypeError: tuple 
>   indices must be integers or slices, not str

I am trying to count the frequency and then write to a `text file`.

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    for word, freq in freqs.items():
        print(word, freq)
    result = word,freq
    return result

def tag_and_save(tagger,text,path):
    clt = clean_text(text)
    tagged_data = tagger.tag(clt)

    freq_tagged_data = get_freq(tagged_data)
    file = open(path,"w",encoding = "UTF8")
    for word,tag in tagged_data:
        file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+str(freq_tagged_data[word])+")\n")
    file.close()
```

I expect the output like this :

> ('*****/DTNN') 3

---

based on the answer of

i changed the function **get_freq()** into :

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freq_dist = {}
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    freq_dist = [(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()]
    return freq_dist
```

but now it display the below error :

> File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 217, in tag_and_save
>     file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+str(freq_tagged_data[word])+")\n")

TypeError: list

> indices must be integers or slices, not str

How to fix this error and what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this might help.

```
import nltk
text = "An an valley indeed so no wonder future nature vanity. Debating all she mistaken indulged believed provided declared. He many kept on draw lain song as same. Whether at dearest certain spirits is entered in to. Rich fine bred real use too many good. She compliment unaffected expression favourable any. Unknown chiefly showing to conduct no."
tokens = [t for t in text.split()]
freqs = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
blah_list = [(k, v) for k, v in freqs.items()]
print(blah_list)
```

This snippet counts the word frequency.

**Edit:** Code is now working.

Comment: What I think the problem might be is the datatype of the return value of get_freq function. You are returning only one single 'word' and 'freq' as a return. You need to create an empty list and append the 'word' & 'freq' to it inside the for loop and then return that entire list.

Comment: ok it print the blash_list  so i tried to use this code in my function now it display an error .  i will edit my question and add the updates

Comment: Ahh. Here I see. In the tag_and_save function, the 'word' is a string type and you should pass an integer in the "freq_tagged_data[word]". Here is a reference site you can have a look at - [link] https://www.stechies.com/typeerror-list-indices-must-integers-slices-not-tuple/ [link]

Comment: I edited the answer so that the code is working now.

Comment: i tried your answer but  still the same error :

`  File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 218, in tag_and_save
    file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+ freq_tagged_data[word] +")\n")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: The question author needs to use `dict` instead of `list`.