# how to fix error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in python

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, word-frequency

based on the previous question i changed my code but still not working.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648501/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-existing-in-a-text-using-nltk/60648925?noredirect=1#comment107308482_60648925)

I have a python script that reads the text and applies preprocess functions in order to do the analysis.
The problem is that I want to count the frequency of words but the system crash and displays the below error.

> File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 219, in tag_and_save
>       file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+ freq_tagged_data[word] +")\n")
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freq_dist = {}
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    freq_dist = [(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()]
    # print(freq_dist)
    return freq_dist

def tag_and_save(tagger,text,path):
    clt = clean_text(text)
    tagged_data = tagger.tag(clt)
    tagged_data = sorted(tagged_data,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    freq_tagged_data = get_freq(tagged_data)
    file = open(path,"w",encoding = "UTF8")
    for word,tag in tagged_data:
        file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+ freq_tagged_data[word] +")\n")
    file.close()
```

if i try to convert word into int()

```
def tag_and_save(tagger,text,path):
    clt = clean_text(text)
    tagged_data = tagger.tag(clt)
    tagged_data = sorted(tagged_data,key=operator.itemgetter(1)) 
    freq_tagged_data = get_freq(tagged_data)
    file = open(path,"w",encoding = "UTF8")
    for word,tag in tagged_data:
        file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+ freq_tagged_data[int(word)] +")\n")
    file.close()
```

it display the below error :

> File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 219, in tag_and_save
>       file.write(word+"/"+tag+" (frequency="+ freq_tagged_data[int(word)] +")\n") ValueError: invalid literal for
>   int() with base 10: ''

the expected output must be like this :

**('*****/DTNN') 3**

Comment: One of the `word`s is an empty string. You cannot convert it to an integer.

Comment: no there is no empty string in the given variable because before it comes to output there is a pre processing  functions for the text

Comment: Please update your code to include the conversion to `int`, and add a _full_ error message.

Comment: i updated my question and add the full error

Comment: What is the value of `word`? It's clearly not a valid base-10 number. `print` it the line above.

Comment: Your `freq_tagged_data` is a list of tuples, I'm not sure how you want to look up words in there? Why are you not working with a dictionary here as `FreqDist` provides?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay  i ma trying to work on text analysis so the value of word for now is the POS tag where it contains the **word itself /tag**  + the number of existing frequency

Comment: You need to pass the frequency of the word into `int()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the frequency of words existing in a text using nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648501/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-existing-in-a-text-using-nltk)

Comment: no it doesn't thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `get_freq()` function. It returns `list` not `dict`:

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    # freq_dist is dict
    freq_dist = {}
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    # freq_dist is list now
    freq_dist = [(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()]
    return freq_dist
```

You have several options to initialize the dictionary:

**`dict` comprehension**

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    return {word: freq for word ,freq in freqs.items()}
```

**`update()` method**

See [update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) documentation for details.

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freq_dist = {}
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    freq_dist.update([(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()])
    return freq_dist
```

**`dict` constructor**

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    # freq_dist is list now
    return dict([(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()])
```

Comment: i tried your answer : and it display this error:
`  File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 224, in tag_and_save
    file.write("{0} /{1} {2} \n".format(word,tag,freq_tagged_data[word]))
KeyError: ''`