# how to fix list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, word-frequency

after 2 previous questions still did not fix the problem. [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648501/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-existing-in-a-text-using-nltk/60648925?noredirect=1#comment107308482_60648925) [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648501/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-existing-in-a-text-using-nltk)

I have a python script that clean text before it goes to analysis text part.

so i have some functions that clean the text and make POS tags in order to split text and tokenize  it.
 **I need to return the word + tags  + frequency of existing.**

the problem is that the function takes  **list of tuple** and at then end the system crash and display the below error :

> File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 221, in tag_and_save
>       file.write("{0} /{1} {2} \n".format(word,tag,freq_tagged_data[word]))
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
def get_freq(tagged):
    freq_dist = {}
    freqs = FreqDist(tagged)
    freq_dist = [(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()]
    # print(freq_dist)
    return freq_dist

def tag_and_save(tagger,text,path):
    clt = clean_text(text)
    tagged_data = tagger.tag(clt)
    print("tagged_data\n\n\n",tagged_data)## **here its a list of tuple [('','')]**

    tagged_data = sorted(tagged_data,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    freq_tagged_data = get_freq(tagged_data)
    file = open(path,"w",encoding = "UTF8")
    for word,tag in tagged_data:

        file.write("{0} /{1} {2} \n".format(word,tag,freq_tagged_data[word]))## the error is here 
    file.close()
```

expected output :
("*****/POS tag") number of frequency.

Comment: This question duplicates your questions

Answer (score 0):

change

```
freq_dist = [(word, freq) for word ,freq in freqs.items()]
```

to

```
for word, freq in freqs.items():
    freq_dist[word] = freq
```

It will probably solve the issue. As you are changing dict to a list in that line.

try this in `tag_and_save`:

```
for word,tag in tagged_data:
    if (word and word != "") and (tag and tag != ""):
        file.write("{0} /{1} {2} \n".format(word,tag,freq_tagged_data[word]))
```

Comment: i tried you answer it display this error :

`File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 223, in tag_and_save
    file.write("{0} /{1} {2} \n".format(word,tag,freq_tagged_data[word]))
KeyError: ''`

Comment: okay, sorry, I made something wrong in the statements, could you please use the updated version and let me know?

Comment: i use your updated answer now it create the txt file but empty

Comment: could you please print your tagged data in a file and share it with me? not all of it definitely, I just want to know the structure of the data.

Comment: this is a part to the tagged data :
` ('', 'وخطة/NN'), ('', 'الإجراءات/DTNNS'), ('', 'الضرورية/DTJJ'), ('', 'لتنفيذ/NN'), ('', 'هذه/DT'), ('', 'النقلة/DTNN'), ('', 'النوعية/DTJJ'), ('', 'المرجوة/DTJJ'), ('', 'حي/NNP'), ('', 'في/IN'), ('', '12019/CD')]`

Comment: but when i tried to write this output to a file it display the below error:
`  File "F:\AIenv\textAnalysis\setup.py", line 257, in tag_and_save
    write_file("tagged_data.txt","".join(tagged_data))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`

Comment: The behavior seems so normal here, all the words are empty. Could you tell me something, look at the first instance: ('', 'وخطة/NN'). What is the word and the tag in this instance?